# Running SonarQube scanner sonar-web-frontend IlligalStateException

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am running the SonarScanner using the sonar-web-frontend-plugin from the commandLine, it picks up the files and runs and I get an execution Failure

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Report processing did not complete successfully
: FAILED

My sonar-project.properties look like this

# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=Test.UI
# this is the name displayed in the SonarQube UI
sonar.projectName=Test.UI
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src/app

# exclude some files and folders (typically dependencies)
sonar.exclusions=bower_components/**/*, node_modules/**/*

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have the Build Breaker plugin installed on your SonarQube instance.

Your project failed its quality gate.

The Build Breaker plugin did its job, and "broke" (returned a non-success status code) your build.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, but its not publishing the results on the ui, do i need to specify a command for this?

Comment: @Jeepers If you use latest version of https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-build-breaker then according to its description results should be published. If not, then please specify what you use, i.e. which plugin do you use and its version.Note that SonarQube developers do not recommend to break the build - http://www.sonarqube.org/why-you-shouldnt-use-build-breaker/

Comment: In fact @Godin I think every version of the Build Breaker plugin ever has published the results. It _can't_ break the build for a QG failure _unless_ the results are published.

Comment: G. Ann- Nothing shows up on my Dashboard for the Project I ran the analysis for. Even though the project gets created. Under project administration it says "No analysis has been performed since creation. The only available section is the configuration" when i check the logs it syas the analysis report is created and I can see it has, why is nothing being posted for this, I can see nothing on the ui?

Comment: What does the server log say?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it was because i had the default JS rules still installed and they can't exist side by side.